# Error in georeferencing using QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, georeferencing

I was georeferencing a tiff image. But the Georeferenced output is showing GCPs only. The image is not being georeferenced.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you refencing and export settings?

Comment: Welcome! The screenshot you provided doesn't show much, only that it is not working. What would be more useful is e.g.: 1. a screenshot of the properties, 2. a screenshot of the georeferencing menu with your settings, 3. the new screenshot of properties. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @Erik! Screenshots of transformation settings and georeferencing is attached. The GCPs are right as I have crosschecked it. But why is this showing this error?

Comment: The error got resolved by changing the transformation @Erik

Comment: Feel free to answer the question on your own, so other users may profit from your new found knowledge. I usually use Helmert transformation for digital maps, and Polynominal for scanned maps.